# Fix NSPredicate

Tags: objective-c, nspredicate

NOTE: employeename is a key in an array of multiply key value pair

NSPredicate to find result of all employee name when user type character wise search

```
 NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"employeename BEGINSWITH[cd] %@", searchtxtField.text];
 NSArray *elementFound= [arr_employeeData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
NSLog(@"arr_add_data=%@",arr_employeeData);

(
        {
        employeename = "Anoop";
        employeeMobile = 11111111;
    },
{
        employeename = "Anoop singh";
        employeeMobile = 11111111;
    },
  {
        employeename = "Anoop kumar";
        employeeMobile = 1133111111;
    },
 {
        employeename = "Vijay kumar";
        employeeMobile = 22222;
    },

)
```

If your type A in search bar he will have to get all results employee name start with A and so on

Comment: I'm only guessing here, but your issue is that `Vijay kumar` is appearing in the output, while you've entered `A` as the search term?

Comment: no i am getting only one means if i type complete anoop then i get single result, if i type anoop kumar complete then i get a result, i need if just type a or an or anoop etc i get all employee name result contain these strings

Comment: Ah, that was completely unclear from your problem description.

Comment: I don't understand. Could you give some results for `elementFound` according to `searchtxtField.text`? Because the `NSPredicate` seems correct, but could it be on your use of the filter that lies the issue?

Comment: You should NSLog the 'elementFound' array. Thats the one with the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess with your predicate is all Ok.
But the result of filtered users will be in

> NSArray *elementFound .

Just print it,and use it next in your program.
Because this method return filtered array by predicate, but not change the original one.
To change original one,

```
    NSMutableArray * mutab = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:arr_employeeData];
    [mutab filterUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

And "mutab" array, will have filtered results